# For loop outputting the wrong answer

Tags: r, function, loops

The code below is an example. My function `testf` works fine when calling `NAME` or `SRC` individually but it doesn't work if I try to do this through a vector - make sense I believe. So I ventured into making it a loop and by rights (from what I do understand) this should work, but it hasn't. It generates an output but it's clearly wrong and I'm not sure why it's doing this. Am I applying this incorrectly? Thanks

```
NAME <- c("SYNOP", "SYNOP", "METAR", "METAR", "SYNOP", "METAR")
AIR <-  c(6.7, 8.3, 9.2, 8.9, 9.1, 8.7)
SRC <- c("WMO", "WMO", "WMO", "ID_3", "ID_3", "WMO")
Example <- data.frame(NAME, AIR, SRC)

require(dplyr)
testf <- function(j) {
Example %>% group_by((j)) %>% summarize(Count=n())
}

testf(NAME)
testf(SRC)

vector <- c("NAME", "SRC")

testf(vector)

for (v in vector) {
testg <- testf(v)
print(testg)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to pass a string to `testf` and have it passed on to `group_by`, you'd have to use the [standard evaluation version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html), which is `group_by_`:

```
testf <- function(j) {
    Example %>% group_by_(.dots = j) %>% summarize(Count=n())
}

# examples:
testf("NAME")
testf(c("NAME", "AIR"))

for (v in c("NAME", "SRC")) {
  print(testf(v))
}
```

See here for an explanation of non-standard evaluation used in the dplyr package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Comment: Perfect thank you, this makes me understand why nothing I changed in the for loop was fixing it

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
testf <- function(j) {
    Example %>% group_by((deparse(j))) %>% summarize(Count=n())
}
```